# Image slider not showing image

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

The image slider doesn't show the image when it is clicked on at the bottom.

What may be the problem?

It shows differently in UC browser and differently in Firefox

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Container for the image gallery -->
  <!-- Full-width images with number text -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="width:100%"><br/>
  </div>
  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  <!-- Image text -->
  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>
  <!-- Thumbnail images -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide({{$i}})" alt="good">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the html that the php code is generating

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and post HTML, CSS,  and Script only. This is not a PHP/Laravel question

Comment: Please recheck the question i have edited it

Comment: Did you include your script before the html ?

Comment: I would suggest you try this out in jsfiddle first. and then post the link here. Would then be good to see. Also, have you tried having anchor tags set up like this ?  `<a href="javascript:plusSlides(-1);">&#10094;</a>` ? Also not sure how the {{$i}} would be working in html unless this is more than html.

Comment: Please update the snippet I made to a [mcve] for example change `"currentSlide({{$i}})` to proper event handling - @Supra - better to use onclick and preventDefault -  the onclick can be asserted in script